# Help with solving this first order separable DE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = r(1 - \frac{x}{K})x$$

for some constant K. We are given the initial value that $x(0) = x_0$

We are given a hint that we should do a change of variable and let $u = \frac{x}{K}$

**Attempt**

$u = \frac{x}{K}$ so $x = Ku$ and $Kdu = dx$. The DE now becomes
$$\frac{du}{dt} = r(1 - u)u$$
after cancelling out the Ks.

This is a separable first order DE, so we bring the u's to one side
$$\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{(1 - u)u}du = \int_{}^{}rdt$$

I'm ashamed to say that I'm stuck on this simple-looking integral. Would appreciate the help. Also, please let me know if my steps until this point are correct.

Thank You

**EDIT**To clarify, I'm stuck on the integral on the left-hand side of the equation. The right side would just be $rt + C$

Comment: 1.) partial fractions 2.) $\log(x)'=1/x$ for $x>0$

Comment: Oh. Sorry for wasting your time. I can't believe I forgot about partial fractions.

Comment: There are several earlier questions about this on this site already, if you get stuck. Search for "logistic equation".

Comment: acutally you don't need partial fractions: just expand $((1-u)u)^{-1}$ and split it at the right place